# Can I pool two different panel data sets?

Tags: regression, time-series, classification, statistical-significance, panel-data

Now I have two panel data which Panel 1 has (2008-2011) 4 years and the other one, Panel 2 has 4 years (2012-2015).  These data sets are micro household data sets structured as panel. So I have 5000 household (130600 individual) in Panel 1 and 4700 household (100000 individual). It's a very large data set. Also I have 25 variables range from education to annual income. 25 variables all same for two data sets. Only the ID's different. (A very simple example for my data sets https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQVAH.jpg) I actually want to analyze correlation between health and income, including different variables such as gender, education etc. If we go back to my problem I want to combine these different panel data sets. But I couldn't find any example about it. I even don't know if it's acceptable.

Comment: What does it mean to have health, education, and so forth that have various values? I think you are asking for regression analysis, not correlation. Please restate question. For example, "I want to see how well health and income are predicted by gender, education etc." Also, if you want to combine health and income to be one variable, that is a different question than to see how the variables can agree with health or income taken separately.

Answer (score 0):

First, when you state:

> I actually want to analyze correlation between health and income,
>   including different variables such as gender, education etc.

you seem a bit confused about correlation. Correlation is a measure of the linear relationship between two variables.  It sounds like you want some kind of regression, although it's not clear yet which type. That depends on how your dependent variable (presumably health) is measured.

Second, the size of your average household seems remarkably large.

Third, to your question: Why not? At least, based on what you've written here, it sounds like the combined data set would be the same as if the people collecting the data had simply done it for more years.